# Why does my Windows desktop process appear to exit immediately with no stdout?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, winapi, stdout

I have a "hello world" Windows desktop application, the source of which comes from [this official walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2019).

When I run this program from Windows Subsystem for Linux, I get behavior I expect: the shell blocks, waiting for the process to exit, and the shell prompt only re-appears once the process has exited. I can then inspect the process exit code (here set to 3, by returning this from `wWinMain`):

```
jim@LAPTOP-SMUS1UJN:/mnt/c/Users/james/source/repos/DesktopApp/x64/Release$ ./DesktopApp.exe  # blocks until I close the window ...
jim@LAPTOP-SMUS1UJN:/mnt/c/Users/james/source/repos/DesktopApp/x64/Release$ echo $?
3
```

*However*, this is not the behavior I get when running the program from Command Prompt or from PowerShell. Here, the process starts, but the shell claims that the process immediately exited, giving me a new prompt immediately! But the process has clearly *not* exited, because the window it created still exists and I can interact with it.

In both cases (Windows Subsystem for Linux, and PowerShell), the process stdout is not printed to the terminal. (Verified with `std::cout << "test"`, which prints nothing to the terminal.)

It's as if the original process has spawned a daemon process to run the win32 stuff. But I don't think that is what's happening, because Windows Subsystem for Linux at least blocks until exit.

When I create a "console" C++ application with Visual Studio, it behaves as expected. The strange early-exit-with-no-output behavior only happens for my "desktop" win32 program.

So, why does Command Prompt or PowerShell claim that the process exits immediately? And where is its stdout?

Comment: Windows apps (as opposed to console apps) are run asynchronously from the command line, always have been. It's the Linux shell that's doing something different.

Comment: If you want the console to block, you can use [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc770297(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>[Jonathan Potter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506413/jonathan-potter) provided the crucial pointers in a comment on the question; to elaborate:</sup>

Any given Windows application falls into one of these two mutually exclusive categories<sup>[1]</sup>:

- ***GUI-subsystem* applications**, such as `Notepad.exe`:

  - Such applications typically create *GUI windows*, and sometimes no UI at all.
  - Due to not being associated with a *console*, they *cannot* write to the standard output (stdout) or standard error (stderr) streams.<sup>[2]</sup>
- ***Console-subsystem* applications**, such as `findstr.exe`:

  - Such applications either *create* a console window when invoked, or run in a *preexisting* one, typically one created by a command-line shell such as `cmd.exe` or PowerShell.
  - They write output to the standard output (stdout) and/or standard error (stderr) output streams.

**(Console-based) command-line shells on Windows**, such as `cmd.exe` and PowerShell:

- **invoke *console-subsystem* applications *synchronously*** and report their *exit code*: via pseudo environment variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` in `cmd.exe`, and via variable `$LASTEXITCODE` in PowerShell.

  - Additionally, the stdout and/or stderr output from such application is printed to the console by default, but can also be captured, redirected, or passed to other *console-subsystem* applications via a pipeline.
- **invoke *GUI-subsystem* applications *asynchronously*** by default, launch-and-forget-it style.

  - That is, the shell by default neither waits for the application process to finish, nor does it report its exit code.
  - However, both shells offer *synchronous* invocation, including exit-code reporting, on an *opt-in* basis:

    - In `cmd.exe`, use `start /WAIT ...` for both synchronous execution and having the exit code reflected in `%ERRORLEVEL%` afterwards; see the [internal `start` command's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start).
    - In PowerShell, use `Start-Process -Wait ...` for synchronous execution; to also get the process exit code, use `$ps = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru ...`, and then examine `$ps.ExitCode` - see the [`Start-Process` cmdlet's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process).

---

By contrast, the **POSIX-like shells** of **WSL** (the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)), such as, by default, `bash`:

- **invoke *both* console-subsystem and GUI-subsystem applications *synchronously*** by default, and reflect the exit code of either application type in the built-in `$?` variable afterwards.
- To opt-into *asynchronous* invocation, use postpositional `&` to perform the invocation from a background *job*; e.g., `(Notepad.exe &)`

  - Note: `(...)` suppresses the shell's job-control status message that `&` triggers (effective in `bash`, `zsh`, and `dash`, but not `ksh`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990428/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] The GUI and the console subsystems are the relevant ones for executables designed to be run by end users directly. Other subsystems exist, as described in this [help topic on the PE format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#windows-subsystem) (the format of executable files on Windows). Tip of the hat to James (the OP) for providing the link.</sup>

<sup>[2] While GUI-subsystem applications can explicitly create a console on demand, such a console is independent of the console of a console-subsystem caller. It is even possible to *attach to* the preexisting console of a console-subsystem caller, but the caller will have no awareness of this, and will therefore not be able to capture, redirect, or pass on any output written to that console by the GUI-subsystem application.</sup>