# ErrorVariable output

Tags: powershell

I'm searching for two days now for a solution or something that helps me to understand why.

For some actions I want to send any error to the "-ErrorVariable create_error". No problem.
After that, I just want the exception of the error message:

```
$create_error = $create_error.Exception
```

The output of the variable is now:

```
$create_error
Access to the path '2021' is denied.
```

But if I use this variable as body text for an email, I get the following email text:

```
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '2021' is denied. 
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) 
    at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) 
    at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.CreateSubdirectoryHelper(String path, Object directorySecurity) 
    at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.CreateSubdirectory(String path) 
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.CreateDirectory(String path, Boolean streamOutput)
```

Sendmail:

```
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $create_error
```

Any ideas how I get in an email only the human readable error message?

Thank you!
Best regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

To get just the error *messages* associated with PowerShell error records collected with the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable):

```
$create_error.ForEach('ToString') # Call .ToString() on all records
```

Note: If your variable contains only a *single* error record (not wrapped in a collection), simply call `.ToString()`, such as when accessing a single error in the session-wide automatic `$Error` collection:

```
Get-Item NoSuch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # provoke an error
# Access the most recent error individually:
$Error[0].ToString() # -> 'Cannot find path '...\NoSuch' because it does not exist.'
```

---

#### Background information:

The **common `-ErrorVariable` parameter collects the *non-terminating* errors that occur during execution of a given command** as [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) objects in an array-like collection ([`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList)) - even if only *one* error is collected.

- Note: *Terminating* errors, by contrast - which cmdlets rarely emit -  *abort the entire command*, so that requests to collect the command's own stream output with common parameters such as `-ErrorVariable` and `-OutVariable` are *not* honored. To handle such errors, you need a [`try` ... `catch` ... `finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333721/45375) for details, and [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) for a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling.

These error records wrap .NET exceptions by supplementing them with additional, PowerShell-relevant metadata, such as the location of the error in a script file (`*.ps1`).

There are two separate fields that may contain the message (string) that characterizes the error at hand best:

- `.Exception.Message`
- optionally, `.ErrorDetails.Message`, which can be used to override `.Exception.Message` in the default display format of the error in the console.

The `.ToString()` method wraps this logic, so it is the simplest way to get the error message.

---

**Sample code**:

Note: Typically, `.ErrorDetails` is `$null`. Setting it requires an extra step when constructing an error record.
Here's an example in PowerShell (though note that it's more common to construct error records in compiled cmdlets):

```
# Create an error record.
$err = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
  [InvalidOperationException]::new('foo'),  # the exception being wrapped
  'errId',             # error ID
  'InvalidOperation',  # category 
  $null                # the target object
)
# Then assign an ErrorDetails instance with a custom message.
$err.ErrorDetails = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorDetails] 'bar'
```

Now, `$err.Exception.Message` reports `'foo'`, and `$err.ErrorDetails.Message` `'bar'`. When you call `.ToString()`, the `.ErrorDetails.Message` value takes precedence; if `.ErrorDetails` were `$null`, `'foo'` would be reported:

```
PS> $err.ToString()
bar
```